# Pronunciation of [ʃ] vs. [s]

Tags: pronunciation

Why, for example, is *Kunst* pronounced [ˈkʊn**st**] and not [ˈkʊn**ʃt**], yet the *st* in *Einstein* is pronounced [ˈaɪnˌ**ʃt**aɪn]?

Is there a rule governing when it is [ʃ] vs. [s]?

Comment: The stress signs are put before the syllable that is stressed and not before the stressed vowel. I have changed that.

Comment: FWIW, Kunst pronounced *is* [ˈkʊnst] in the southwest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Somewhere in the transition from Middle High German to New High German, the clusters [sk], [st] and [sp] became [ʃ], [ʃt] and [ʃp], respectively, when they were in the onset of a syllable.

So, in German words "st" and "sp" are pronounced [ʃt] and [ʃp] only when they occur at the beginning of a syllable. In "Einstein", this is the case; in "Kunst" it is not.

Some remarks:

- Foreign words may have the pronunciation [st] or [sp] at the beginning of a syllable; e.g. "ein Star" [st] = a celebrity; but "ein Star" [ʃt] = a starling.
- In the northern parts of the German speaking area, some speakers only use [st] and [sp]; in some southern parts some speakers use [ʃt] and [ʃp] even when it is in the coda of the syllable.
  <sup>This can be used in mocking of dialects. For example a typical Hamburger will say "ich bin über einen [sp]itzen [st]ein ge[st]olpert. And a cliché Swabian will ask "woischd?" for "weißt du?"</sup>
- "Erkenntnisproblem" is pronounced with a [sp] and not with [ʃp] because the compound can be splitted as "Erkenntnis-Problem" but not as "Erkenntni-Sproblem".

Comment: I hate to correct your Swabian because it is a bit tangential, but I think it would be "woischd". At least that is how Pferdle says it.

Comment: Kennsch scho mei schea Schweschda Grischdiene?

Comment: @NikolajK Noi. A schees Xsicht däd i et schnell vergessa.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, "st" is usually pronounced [ʃt] at the beginning of a syllable and [st] in the middle or the end. This is analogously true for "sp"

The "sp" in "Erkenntnisproblem" is not a real "sp", as this is a compound noun ("Erkenntnis-Problem").

Remark: this is not true in the southwest of Germany, where real  "st"/"sp" are always pronounced [ʃt]/[ʃp], no matter where they occur in a word. In the north, the opposite is often true (i.e. "[st]/[sp] in all cases).

Comment: Actually, it's about the beginning of a syllable and not a word. E.g. "verstehen" is not really a compound since "ver-" is not a word but solely a prefix. But essentially you are right, of course.

Comment: @Chris: You are right, of course. And a tiny bit faster than me :)  I edited my answer.

Comment: Even in the Southwest of Germany, the "sp" in "Erkenntnisproblem" remains [sp].

Comment: Edited - although i thought this was clear from my original answer already.

Answer (score 5):

"Erkenntnisproblem" is constructed of two words, "Erkenntnis" and "Problem". The two words keep their pronunciation when combined.

The word "Kunst" has the "st" at the end, there it stays "s-t". However in several dialects, including Swiss German, it will be spoken as "sch-t".